# pyarrow problem: No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarrow_python.so'

Tags: apt, 18.04, python

I'm trying to install pyarrow using pip on Ubuntu 18. I'm using python 3.7

It fails with this message:

```
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-i9sinxwj/pyarrow/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    -- Finished cmake for pyarrow
    -- Running cmake --build for pyarrow
    cmake --build . --config release --
    Scanning dependencies of target lib_pyx
    [ 33%] Compiling Cython CXX source for lib...
    [ 33%] Built target lib_pyx
    Scanning dependencies of target lib
    [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lib.dir/lib.cpp.o
    make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarrow_python.so', needed by 'release/lib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'.  Stop.
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:99: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/lib.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lib.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 2
```

I've tried to find package the file belongs to using:

```
apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarrow_python.so`
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

For your information Python Arrow [is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3-arrow&searchon=names) in all modern Ubuntu versions.

You can install it for Python 2 with

```
sudo apt-get install python-arrow
```

and/or for Python 3 with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-arrow
```

Comment: Anyone who got confused as I did, there are two similarly named python packages 'arrow' and 'pyarrow'.  The apt package contains arrow https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (a datetime library) and not https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/